# In ModernCV "classic" how to reorder the contact details?

Tags: moderncv

Like how to move the website address to the top? There are some answers for this already but they are for the "banking" style etc.

[image]

The [code](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter-2015-version/sttkgjcysttn) is as follows

```latex
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
```

I rearranged the above lines but it doesn't change anything.

Full [code](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter-2015-version/sttkgjcysttn):

```latex
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: Please always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It'll make it easier for people see your configuration and suggest modifications. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase added it

Comment: Please add your code starting with  `\documentclass...`  and ending with `\end{document}` . As you mentioned options and style are important  for the solution.

Comment: @SimonDispa it is there in the code link I posted. Since it is very big I haven't included it. Should I include the entire tex?

Comment: Well... as it is a can not compile you code. Please help the helpers. Post a code you can compile in your system. Just what is needed to generate the posted image.

Comment: @SimonDispa added it.

Comment: Please notice the "Minimal" word in the "Minimal Working Example" link I gave above. Make it easy for people to help you.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moderncv package does not make this very easy. To do it you basically need to redefine the `\makecvhead` command for the classic style and rearrange the commands it uses.

One way you can do this is by using the `\patchcmd` command from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Put this at the end of your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% patch the \makecvhead command to rearrange the order
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%
    % This is the original order we are replacing
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}%
    \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}%
    \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    % END OF OLD LIST
}{%
    %
    % The new order of the elements are determined by the lines below
    % This is what you need to change if you want to rearrange them.
    %
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\makenewline\bornsymbol\@born}%
    \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    % END OF NEW LIST
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The `\patchcmd` command replaces some of the code in the original definition with new code. Here you see two lists of commands for the ordering of the information in the heading. The first is the original order we're going to replace. The second list is the code we're replacing it with. So if we arrange the lines here we rearrange the order of the contents.

I've put the homepage and email addresses at the top compared to the original order. You might want to customize it more. Hopefully the commands used make it clear what each line does. Just rearrange the lines as you like.

[image: reordered heading for moderncv]

Comment: Thank you very much. Initially, it didn't work. But I saw that I was using XeLaTeX 2020 in overleaf once I changed it to XeLaTeX 2021 it worked.